# Is it possible to merge an existing translated .properties file with new methods from a GWT Messages file

Tags: java, gwt, compilation, language-translation

I am working on a GWT project working toward providing application in various languages.

We are using the draft compile feature of GWT to provide .properties files from the Messages class

```
package com.gfi.hosted.core.application.i18n;
    @Generate(format = "com.google.gwt.i18n.server.PropertyCatalogFactory",
    fileName = "LocalizableResource",
    locales = {"de_DE"})
    public interface OurMessages extends Messages {

    public static OurMessages INSTANCE = GWT.create(OurMessages.class);

    @DefaultMessage("An Example String Already Translated")
    String anExampleStringAlreadyTranslated();

    @DefaultMessage("A Newly Introduced String")
    String aNewlyIntroducedString();
}
```

our translated LocalizableResource_de.properties contains

```
# Messages from com.gfi.hosted.core.application.i18n.Msgs
# Source locale de_DE

anExampleStringAlreadyTranslated=Ein Beispiel String bereits übersetzt
```

compile seems to be totally ignoring any new methods, what am I missing?

Comment: Is `de_DE` your default locale? If not, GWT won't complain and simply fall back on your default.

Comment: Hi Thanks for quick response, no our default lang is en_US, I have also tried with 
@Default("en_US")
set
my problem is the new strings are not populated in the resulting LocalizableResource_de.properties on compile, am I trying to do the impossible, or just missed something?

Comment: Ah ha! Its working, I have a very long OurMessages file (c.5000 lines) and the newly untranslated strings being inserted inline in between the original translated strings, I didn't spot them! Not sure why but I was expecting to see them at the top! thanks Baz for your time